# Delay Firing of Function Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my form I am using jquery's autocomplete. It is on a text box but makes it look like a dropdown. It works great.

I use a .change call on this text box to do some other stuff.  In that .change call/function I call another function.  My problem is that the other function call seems to fire before the value in my autocomplete field actually gets the value I select.

```
$('#account1').change(function(){
  $('#sub_account1').html('');
  $('#object_code1').html('');
  $('#sub_object_code1').html('');      
  $('#kfs_acct_1').val('');
  change_object_codes(1);
});
```

Example, in my text field I type 'H' and select 'Hello World' from the autocomplete list that show.  Before 'Hello World' shows/gets set in my text box, change_object_codes(1) fires.  There is code in change_object_code() that needs to work on $('#account1').val(), but it doesn't see it because it isn't set yet.  Sigh!

I found if I put an alert('yo'); on the first line of my .change block it slows it up enough so $('#account1).val() gets set before change_object_code fires.  But, obviously, I do not want that in there.

I'm wondering if anyone has a way to prevent change_object_codes() from running before my text box gets the value I select.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Call your "other function" in the autocomplete's callback.

Comment: j08691: Thanks, that did the trick.  At least I see no other problems at the present that doing such may cause.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at jquery's autocomplete api here: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change You'll see that you need to be using its event-change handling.

So, when you invoke autocomplete (which btw, should really also be in your example) it should look something like this:

```
$( "#account1" ).autocomplete({
  change: function( event, ui ) {
    change_object_codes(1);
}
});
```